# Сортировка данных в мульти-индексе

Tags: python, сортировка, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Есть большой csv файл c такими данными:

```
20180723,100100,112030.0,3
20180723,100100,112030.0,12
20180723,100200,112060.0,1
20180723,100300,112580.0,3
20180723,100300,112580.0,1
20180723,100300,112580.0,1
20180723,100400,112580.0,4
20180723,100400,112570.0,23
20180723,100500,112570.0,2
```

Разбитый на интервалы по 5 минут. Подскажите, как в каждой 5-ти минутке отсортировать столбец ['last'] от большего значения в меньшему?

```
df = pd.read_csv('d://History/ti.csv', sep=',',
                        names=['date', 'time', 'last', 'vl'],
                        parse_dates={'datetime': ['date', 'time']},
                        index_col='datetime')

grouped = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='5min'), 'last'])['vol'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = grouped.sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[1,0])
```

или сразу одной командой:

```
res = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='5min'), 'last'])['vl']
         .sum()
         .sort_index(ascending=[1,0]))
```

результат:

```
In [101]: res
Out[101]:
datetime             last
2018-07-23 10:00:00  112580.0     9
                     112570.0    23
                     112060.0     1
                     112030.0    15
2018-07-23 10:05:00  112570.0     2
Name: vl, dtype: int64
```